# Subtract start date from the end date of the row before - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not able to subtract from the start date the end date of the row above (like in the image) to create a column where I can see if there has been gaps of time between rows.

[image]

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output. Have you taken a look on LAG/LEAD-functions in T-SQL ?

Comment: "Subtracting" dates doesn't make a lot of sense. Dates aren't numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I use this and it worked: DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG([EndDate]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Client] ORDER BY [EndDate]), [StartDate]) as [DaysDiff]

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
select *, datediff(days,lag(cast(end_date as date),1) 
over(partition by client,unique_id order by end_date),
cast(start_date as date)) 
as day_gap
from tablename
```

The datediff function will vary depending on the dialect of SQL you're using. You can check the syntax online for that particular dialect